# Launcher can't cope with "nautilus /home/user/Ubuntu One/Biologie"

Tags: nautilus, launcher

I tried to set up a launcher using the following command:

`nautilus /home/user/Ubuntu One/Biologie`

But if I start the launcher nautilus will try to open the folder `/homer/user/Ubuntu` and `/One/Biologie`.

Any suggestions how to solve the problem without changing the folders name from `Ubuntu One` in `UbuntuOne`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an escape char to handle spaces, this will work.

`nautilus /home/user/Ubuntu\ One/Biologie`

Comment: welcome, dont forget "\ `" is the way! :D